# Setting up multisite with nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, multisite

Having some problems setting up the following setup with nginx:

- example.com
- example.com/gb/en

These are laravel sites and the gb/en is the first of more that will be added. Root works obvs but I can't get /gb/en to point at the /gb/en/public folder.

I have tried a bunch of things but this is my current conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /home/forge/www.example.com/public;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers TEST;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /gb/en {
        root /home/forge/www.example.com/gb/en/public;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

You can see my location block in there which I have tried a number of different ways but to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

So I've got one step closer once I realised that the sub folders in the url also get added to the root directory:

```
location /gb/en/ {
    root /home/forge/www.example.com/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?url=$uri;
}
```

So, my files are under /public/gb/en/public but the above resolves to /public/gb/en/index.php

How can I get /gb/en/ to resolve to public/gb/en/public/index.php?

Many thanks ;)

EDIT:

The idea came to me suddenly - use a symlink! I symlinked the /gb/en to the public folder in a separate folder and it worked a treat ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a symlink in the end to achieve this. I symlinked /gb/en to the public folder in another location and it did what I was after ;)

EDIT - I later found that this also had problems with sub pages but then found this example and it helped to achieve what I wanted to in the first place https://gist.github.com/noeldiaz/08a1211a7c47f21f7083

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest to copy the `try_files` line into the `/en/gb` block. In that folder or site you are not specifying the extensions you would like to use as you are doing in the one that works.

Try this:

```
location /gb/en {
    root /home/forge/www.example.com/gb/en/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

However, if the content of `/en/gb` is related to the site, setting this up directly in Laravel might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. These are all seperate sites and seperate repos so can't handle it on the Laravel side. I did try this but it still resolves to the /home/forge/www.example.com/public folder rather than /home/forge/www.example.com/gb/en/public

Comment: Any further help with this please?